Unable to resolve value for the parameter in Consume node
In my flow i set variable operation as :payload.operation then in Consume node i want to get it's value


Variable value is set corectly

I also include xml of my flow:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:netsuite="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/netsuite" xmlns:wsc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc/current/mule-wsc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/netsuite http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/netsuite/current/mule-netsuite.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="a532976e-413b-4f47-bc8f-3e79e6de1417" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="276e5d43-bd49-4a82-b7c6-934288334aca" >
        <db:my-sql-connection host="mudb.learn.mulesoft.com" port="3306" user="mule" password="mule" database="training" />
    </db:config>
    <wsc:config name="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" doc:name="Web Service Consumer Config" doc:id="a5692620-4f26-4b11-be70-b822710d6c0d" >
        <wsc:connection wsdlLocation="http://dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL" service="Calculator" port="CalculatorSoap12" soapVersion="SOAP12" address="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx"/>
    </wsc:config>
    <flow name="api-accountsFlow" doc:id="7a942ae2-4422-46ba-b57d-38bd37ec9f82" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Get Accounts Listener" doc:id="a1873bcc-b9f1-4cf7-a405-a1c835cdf69c" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/calculator" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="0b885797-7da1-4932-9183-869b5a670943" >
            <when expression='#[payload.operation=="Add" or payload.operation=="Subtract" or payload.operation=="Mul" or payload.operation=="Divide"]'>
                <set-variable value="#[payload.operation]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="5c4da028-7ae8-43e6-ac35-84de6c3b4666" variableName="operation" />
                <ee:transform doc:name="Transform JSON Request to XML" doc:id="86f3eebe-0050-4800-9c08-7167ded759d9" >
                    <ee:message >
                        <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://tempuri.org/
---
{
 ("ns0#" ++ vars.operation): { 
 
        ns0#intA: payload.val1,
        ns0#intB: payload.val2
    } 
}
]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                </ee:transform>
                <wsc:consume doc:name="Consume" doc:id="091e6ca8-a78d-4a6f-b947-679235f7bfa4" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" operation="#[vars.operation]"/>
                <ee:transform doc:name="Transform JSON Request to XML1" doc:id="6b77fd85-8af7-4f96-a299-2b64445ede0b" >
                    <ee:message >
                        <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
 ]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                </ee:transform>
            </when>
            <otherwise >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="b4a8341c-a265-4c60-ab58-9b42d899c8fd" />
                <set-payload value="=== Operation Not Found ===" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="f8436921-0612-44b5-b12d-7dac7bfd7c2d" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>


When i run my flow i get
org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ValueResolvingException: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ValueResolvingException: Unable to resolve value for the parameter: operation
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.OperationParameterValueResolver.getParameterValue(OperationParameterValueResolver.java:101)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.metadata.MetadataMediator.getMetadataKeyObjectValue(MetadataMediator.java:426)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.metadata.MetadataMediator.getMetadata(MetadataMediator.java:181)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.lambda$getMetadata$21(ExtensionComponent.java:656)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1102)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1020)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.lambda$getMetadata$22(ExtensionComponent.java:655)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.runWithMetadataContext(ExtensionComponent.java:793)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.getMetadata(ExtensionComponent.java:654)
    at org.mule.runtime.metadata.internal.MuleMetadataService.lambda$getComponentMetadata$7(MuleMetadataService.java:218)
    at org.mule.runtime.metadata.internal.MuleMetadataService.exceptionHandledMetadataFetch(MuleMetadataService.java:174)
    at org.mule.runtime.metadata.internal.MuleMetadataService.getComponentMetadata(MuleMetadataService.java:217)
    at org.mule.runtime.metadata.internal.MuleMetadataService.getOperationMetadata(MuleMetadataService.java:116)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.bean.lazy.LazyMetadataService.lambda$getOperationMetadata$4(LazyMetadataService.java:100)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.bean.lazy.LazyMetadataService.getOperationMetadata(LazyMetadataService.java:100)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.services.metadata.MuleAgentMetadataService.lambda$getOperationMetadata$2(MuleAgentMetadataService.java:75)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.services.metadata.MuleAgentMetadataService.withMetadataService(MuleAgentMetadataService.java:145)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.services.metadata.MuleAgentMetadataService.getOperationMetadata(MuleAgentMetadataService.java:75)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.external.handlers.metadata.MetadataRequestHandler.lambda$getOperationMetadata$3(MetadataRequestHandler.java:206)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.util.ResponseHelper.response(ResponseHelper.java:88)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.external.handlers.metadata.MetadataRequestHandler.getOperationMetadata(MetadataRequestHandler.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.rest.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.rest.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required parameter 'operation' was assigned with value '#[vars.operation]' which resolved to null. Required parameters need to be assigned with non null values
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.resolver.RequiredParameterValueResolverWrapper.resolve(RequiredParameterValueResolverWrapper.java:67)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.LazyExecutionContext.lambda$lazy$1(LazyExecutionContext.java:61)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedSupplier.get(CheckedSupplier.java:25)
    at org.mule.runtime.api.util.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:75)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.LazyExecutionContext.getParameter(LazyExecutionContext.java:78)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.OperationParameterValueResolver.lambda$getParameterValue$1(OperationParameterValueResolver.java:95)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.OperationParameterValueResolver.getParameterValue(OperationParameterValueResolver.java:78)
    ... 81 more

After some tests I think problem may be in this part:   ("ns0#" ++ vars.operation):  because from postman I get this error:
Error consuming the operation [Subtract], the request body is not a valid XML

Please use code blocks format for code, errors and logs.

Is that the complete error message and stack trace?

I added complete error message now

Don't use single line format for the error. Use code fences same as for code. It is unreadable as it was. I fixed the format of the error for you this time.

Thank you! I begin to suspect that problem ins in this part of code: %dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://tempuri.org/
{
("ns0#" ++ vars.operation):  {
ns0#intA: payload.val1,
ns0#intB: payload.val2
}
}
and because of this line "  ("ns0#" ++ vars.operation): " XML is not set correctly

Which exact versions of Mule, Web Service Consumer and Java are you using?

The exception shared is unrelated to the error you are receiving in the client.

Then you can return your answer regarding " Unable to resolve value" I will tag it as correct and create separate questions about error returned from postmen

Done. Please test if it resolves the original exception.

I suspect that because the variable is set with the value from a JSON payload it maybe confusing Mule. The image shows the variable operation is a JSON. Try assigning it as a Java output to remove the JSON format from the string:
<set-variable value="#[output application/java --- payload.operation]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="5c4da028-7ae8-43e6-ac35-84de6c3b4666" variableName="operation" />


Thanks a lot for this comment but I suspect that the real problem is in ("ns0#" ++ vars.operation): in transform message because regardless of that java error that appears in debug, postman returns this: Error consuming the operation [Divide], the request body is not a valid XML and same goes for all operations : [add] etc. It works if I set it to static ns0#Add:  or ns0#Multiply: but  my main task was to make it dynamic. Anyway, thanks for all the suggestions provided!
